# Big O notation depend on matrix size only or data type(integer, Boolean) as well?

Tags: javascript, math, computer-science, mathematical-optimization, quantization

Does the big O notation depend on the dimension of the matrix only? or it will depend on data type(integer or boolean) as well.

Suppose if I have two matrices of size mat=M x N and I have to multiply them. If the data type of matrix is integer the run time on the computer is different but if the data type is bolean[+1,-1] the run time on the computer is reduced. How I can write big O notation by taking into account data type as well.

Comment: How do you multiply `true` and `false`? And why is `true === +1` and `false === -1`? o.O

Comment: _"In computer science, big O notation is used to classify algorithms according to how their running time or space requirements grow **as the input size grows**."_ ([Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation))

Comment: I am working on communication-related work, so quantize my matrix to lower bits, their simulation time is different, now I am struggling to represent them in big O notation, data type (16 bits, 8 bits , 2 bits), the dimension of the matrix is same in all cases. Their big-O notation will be different or same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't take it into account; the big-O is the same in all cases. Big-O is about *scaling*; how much *more* work do you do as the size of the input grows, relative to the baseline work?

Unless the algorithm scales to arbitrary bit lengths for each element of the matrix, the difference between boolean and integer would be a constant multiplier, and constant multipliers are ignored in big-O notation. For a choice of 16 vs. 8 vs. 2 vs. 1, it's not really arbitrary growth; 16 bits may take 16 times as long as 1 bit for a 10x10 matrix, but if it also takes 16 times as long as 1 bit for a 20x20, the scaling factor is the same.

Note: On real hardware, there may be more noticeable changes in performance (matrices that stop fitting in a cache line, or in cache at all can change behavior significantly), but big-O is about idealized computing devices, with no such limitations.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @ShadowRanger, can you please add some research paper to support your answer

Comment: @farzanahassan: Big-O is a definition of a particular way of describing algorithmic scaling, it's not tied to research papers in the way you seem to want (research papers accept the definition, and research algorithms with improved big-O performance). I'd start with [reading Wikipedia's definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).